# Bookmarklet for opening page and then modifying its content

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am trying to make a bookmarklet, that navigates to http://projects.csail.mit.edu/church/wiki/ChurchServ and then inserts some code into the input-box on this site.

I was trying this:

```
<a href="javascript:
var w=window.open('http://projects.csail.mit.edu/church/wiki/ChurchServ','_blank');
w.onload=function(){w.getElementsByClassName('scheme-comment')[0].textContent='my code...';};
">Klick me!</a>
```

It is loading the page but does not modify it. Whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can not open a window of different domain and modify its content by JS because of same origin policy.

See the last question on this [FAQ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open#FAQ)

Also note `w` is a `window` object. `window` object doesn't have `getElementsByClassName` method. That method belongs to `document`. But you can not access the document object due to same-origin-policy